# UPDATE query with CakePHP

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

I know I can use `$this->Model->save()` to update a particular record if I pass the id in, but how can I update a single field on that row?

I have a `users` table with a `balance` field. I want to update the `balance` field based on what's already there.

For example, a user has $20 in the balance field. I want to add $1 to make it $21. The only way I know how to do this is to use

```
$balance = $this->Model->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $userId),
    'fields' => array('User.balance')
));

$this->Model->save(array(
    'User' => array('id' => $userId, 'balance' => $balance['User']['balance'] + $credit)
));
```

How can I get that all into one `save` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->layout = 'admin_layout';
        $this->Model->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Model->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid model'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The model has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The model could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->Model->read(null, $id);
        }
        $datd = $this->Model->find('list');
        $this->set('data', $datd);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

This should do:

```
$this->User->updateAll(array('User.balance' =>'User.balance + 1'), array('User.id' => $id));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->Model->saveField('balance','balance+1');
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Beat me :) Here's API link http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveField

Comment: I'm not even a CakePHP guy (more of a CodeIgniter guy) and I figured it out! Sorry!

Comment: Just an extra note: make sure `$this->Model->id` is set before the call

Comment: I looked into using this before I wrote my post and should've mentioned it. Sorry. It doesn't work, it runs this query: `UPDATE database.users SET balance = 'balance+1' WHERE database.users.id = '26'`. The `balance` field is a decimal (20, 4).

Comment: I have no idea why that doesn't work. Maybe try hardcoding the query and seeing if that works?